# Colorbox Iframe Resizing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resize an colorbox containing an iframe. The following code works fine on normal sites but in Drupal it is having problems. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? The colorbox is supposed to resize to the size of the content plus a specified offset in the Resize function.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.formToWizard = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({  
            submitButton: "" 
        }, options); 

        //Resize the colorbox
        function Resize_Box(){
            var x = $("body").width();
            var y = $("body").height()+30;
            parent.$.fn.colorbox.resize({
                innerWidth: 600,
                innerHeight: y
            });
        }

        var element = this;

        var steps = $(element).find("fieldset");
        var count = steps.size();
        var submmitButtonName = "#" + options.submitButton;
        $(submmitButtonName).hide();

        // 2
        $(element).before("<div class='nav-container'><div class='inner-container'><ul id='steps'></ul></div></div>");

        steps.each(function(i) {
            $(this).wrap("<div id='step" + i + "'></div>");
            $(this).append("<p id='step" + i + "commands'></p>");

            // 2
            var name = $(this).find("legend").html();
            $("#steps").append("<li id='stepDesc" + i + "'><div class='circle'></div></li>");

            if (i == 0) {
                createNextButton(i);
                selectStep(i);
            }
            else if (i == count - 1) {
                $("#step" + i).hide();
                createPrevButton(i);
                createNextButton(i);
            }
            else {
                $("#step" + i).hide();
                createPrevButton(i);
                createNextButton(i);
            }
            Resize_Box();
        });

        //Create the previous button
        function createPrevButton(i) {
            var stepName = "step" + i;
            $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<a href='#' id='" + stepName + "Prev' class='prev'>< Back</a>");

            $("#" + stepName + "Prev").bind("click", function(e) {
                $("#" + stepName).hide();
                $("#step" + (i - 1)).show();
                $(submmitButtonName).hide();
                selectStep(i - 1);
                //Only resize if going back to the first step since it has fewer options
                if(i==1){
                    Resize_Box();
                }
            });
        }

        //Create the next button
        function createNextButton(i) {
            var stepName = "step" + i;
            if(i != count-1)
            {
                $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<a href='#' id='" + stepName + "Next' class='next notvalid'>Next ></a>");
                $("#" + stepName + "Next").bind("click", function(e) {
                    var currentq = document.querySelector('div#step'+i+' input[type=radio]').name;
                    if($('input[name='+currentq+']:checked').length > 0) {
                        $("#" + stepName).hide();
                        $("#step" + (i + 1)).show();
                        if (i + 2 == count)
                            $(submmitButtonName).show();
                        selectStep(i + 1);
                        //Only resize if going from the first step since all other steps have more options
                        if(i == 0) {
                            Resize_Box();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<input id='SaveAccount' type='submit' value='Submit' class='next notvalid'/>");
            }
        }

        function selectStep(i) {
            $("#steps li").removeClass("current");
            $("#stepDesc" + i).addClass("current");
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing $ with jQuery. By default I don't believe Drupal allows the $ as a shortcut due to potential compatibility issues with other libraries.